# ii have updated my app from v12 to v20 in devextreme getting these errors?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

[see errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgN07.png)

i don't know what to do , I am pretty new at c# this app is given to me to study but these errors show up.
if anyone know or previously encountered these type of error help me

Comment: Do a clean build from the build menu.  Also check in Solution Explorer for any yellow items including under reference.  When you install new version of app the reference location probably changed and you need to delete old reference and add again.

Comment: i have done this nothing happened

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happened?  Are you still getting errors?  Are any references or objects yellow?  Did you do a clean build?

Comment: yes i am still getting errors and no refrence is yellow and i did clean build also

Comment: Getting same errors?  Open the csproj file with notepad and check if locations of files are correct.  Also check the bin folder and make sure any dll have the correct date.  The clean build would remove any dll from the bin folder and then copy from source location.  When adding dll to a project you should never copy the dll to bin folder.  You should always use Add Existing and then browse to where original dll is located so when you do a clean build the latest version of the file is added to the bin. I think you are missing a dll in the bin folder.

Comment: Do you know how to add references manually?

Comment: From project menu VS either "Add Reference" or "Add Existing Item".  Then Browse to location of where dll is located in the debug folder of other project.

Comment: i have updated the project and the project updated successfully but still, it is asking for old references

Comment: Open csproj file with notepad and check location of references.  The clean build should delete the dll from the bin folder.  As last resort I usually delete the obj and bin folder from project which forces everything to get rebuild.  As a safety precaution usually backup folder incase something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Breaking changes were introduced between versions 12 and 20. You need to review the [Version History page](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/versionhistory) and do a comparison of what has changed and how to correct the errors.

**In short**: some of the code you used with the DevExpress controls in v12 is no longer valid with the 2020 version.

For instance, many of your errors are covered in this breaking change notification:

[The ColumnView.CustomColumnDisplayText event no longer provides the RowHandle parameter](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/BC2550/the-columnview-customcolumndisplaytext-event-no-longer-provides-the-rowhandle-parameter).

Because you are going from such a low version to a more recent version, you will likely need to do a comparison between v12 and v16 and then from v16 to v20. You can filter the breaking changes by suite/product.

Searching those specific error messages in the Support Center should also yield the tickets that provide information on how to fix your errors. And you can also contact DevExpress support to request assistance.